# How to make Photoshop connect Gujarati characters?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, text

I am using Photoshop CS6.

Recently when I try to type in our local language "Gujarati" via [Google Input tools](https://www.google.com/inputtools/windows/) (I tried without Google tools also, with Gujarati fonts), the typed text not showing joined word and characters correctly.

This is how it looks in Photoshop:

[image]

It is working correctly everywhere except Photoshop. This is how is should look (typed in Chrome):

[image]

To better understand my problem, there is a similar [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23402552). That problem is for Android and my question is for Photoshop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if this works for "Gujarati", it does for other languages:

1. Make sure you have ligatures turned on:

   [image]
2. Check the features of your own language:

   [image]
3. In preferences, check you have the right mode (if it's not after changing it restart Photoshop):

   [image]

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and unfortunately the said 'ligatures' options are disabled.

Comment: Hi Friend I'm facing same issue and I have follow the steps. The Middle eastern features is disable you can see it by this link http://3emperor.com/Screenshot_5.png. I have also tried to change it from edit->preferences->type.. http://3emperor.com/Screenshot_6.png but I not get the result. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

**QUICK SOLUTION**

Here's the quick solution I've found (I am using Photoshop CC).

Install the [**Noto Sans Gujarati**](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-gujr) fonts to your system and then follow these two simple steps.

1. Go to Preferences > Tools > Middle Eastern and South Asian

   [image: Select Middle Eastern and South Asian]
2. Write anything on Google Translate or any other document like a Word file, then copy the entire text to Photoshop and make sure you've selected **Noto Sans Gujarati** as displayed in this screenshot:

   [image: Select Noto Sans Gujarati]

Comment: Is this font commercial or free?

Answer (score 0):

I am working with Photoshop CC 2019 and I tried this and other mentioned steps and non of them are working for me.

[image]

The best thing that worked for me is [Kohinoor Gujarati](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=kohinoor%20gujarati) fonts. Use this font as your fonts and use google input tool or windows inbuilt language preference as Gujarati and type whatever you like; photoshop will recognize all the letters.

[image]

Enjoy writing in Gujarati...