# How to make Indesign connect Gujarati characters?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

I am using Indesign of CS6.

Recently when I try to type our local language "Gujarati" via Google Input tools ,Typed text not showing "Joint word" correctly.

like this

[image]

[Same problem with photoshop but its solved](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/49512/how-to-make-photoshop-connect-gujarati-characters)

Comment: So it worked before? Please help us to help you. You are not typing in a query into an automated system, you are asking humans for help.

Comment: Its worked before in photoshop.